# Multidimensional RNN on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a 2D RNN in the context of human action classification (joints on one axis of the RNN and time on the other) and have been searching high and low for something in Tensorflow that could do the job.

I heard of `GridLSTMCell` ([internally](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GridLSTMCell) and [externally](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/grid_rnn/python/ops/grid_rnn_cell.py) contributed) but couldn't get it to work with `dynamic_rnn` (accepts a 3-D tensor but I'd have to provide a 4-D tensor [batchsize, max_time, num_joints, n_features]).

Additionally, `ndlstm` is also a (somewhat unknown) [part](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ndlstm) of the TF library which basically uses a normal 1-D LSTM and transposes the output to feed it into a second 1-D LSTM. This was also advocated [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1453#issuecomment-194976468) but am not too sure if it's correct / if it's the same idea as what I would need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully tried using `GridLSTM` and `ndlstm` in tensorflow.

I'm not sure on how to convert a 4D Tensor into a 3D one for it to be accepted by a `dynamic_rnn` but I think this might give you an idea on how to use `GridLSTM`:

```
def reshape_to_rnn_dims(tensor, num_time_steps):
    return tf.unstack(tensor, num_time_steps, 1)


class GridLSTMCellTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num_features = 1
        self.time_steps = 1
        self.batch_size = 1
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.time_steps, self.num_features])
        self.cell = grid_rnn.Grid1LSTMCell(num_units=8)

    def test_simple_grid_rnn(self):
        self.input_layer = reshape_to_rnn_dims(self.input_layer, self.time_steps)
        tf.nn.static_rnn(self.cell, self.input_layer, dtype=tf.float32)

    def test_dynamic_grid_rnn(self):
        tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.cell, self.input_layer, dtype=tf.float32)


class BidirectionalGridRNNCellTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num_features = 1
        self.time_steps = 1
        self.batch_size = 1
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.time_steps, self.num_features])
        self.cell_fw = grid_rnn.Grid1LSTMCell(num_units=8)
        self.cell_bw = grid_rnn.Grid1LSTMCell(num_units=8)

    def test_simple_bidirectional_grid_rnn(self):
        self.input_layer = reshape_to_rnn_dims(self.input_layer, self.time_steps)
        tf.nn.static_bidirectional_rnn(self.cell_fw, self.cell_fw, self.input_layer, dtype=tf.float32)

    def test_bidirectional_dynamic_grid_rnn(self):
        tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(self.cell_fw, self.cell_bw, self.input_layer, dtype=tf.float32)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.test.main()
```

Apparently, `ndlstm`s accept 4D tensors with the shape `(batch_size, height, width, depth)`, I have these tests (one involving the use of tensorflow's `ctc_loss`. Also found an [example](https://github.com/johnsmithm/handwritten-tf-1.0/blob/master/handwritten_models.py#L810-#L817) of its use with conv2d):

```
class MultidimensionalRNNTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.num_classes = 26
        self.num_features = 32
        self.time_steps = 64
        self.batch_size = 1 # Can't be dynamic, apparently.
        self.num_channels = 1
        self.num_filters = 16
        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, self.time_steps, self.num_features, self.num_channels])
        self.labels = tf.sparse_placeholder(tf.int32)

    def test_simple_mdrnn(self):
        net = lstm2d.separable_lstm(self.input_layer, self.num_filters)

    def test_image_to_sequence(self):
        net = lstm2d.separable_lstm(self.input_layer, self.num_filters)
        net = lstm2d.images_to_sequence(net)

    def test_convert_to_ctc_dims(self):
        net = lstm2d.separable_lstm(self.input_layer, self.num_filters)
        net = lstm2d.images_to_sequence(net)

        net = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, self.num_filters])

         W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([self.num_filters,
                                     self.num_classes],
                                    stddev=0.1, dtype=tf.float32), name='W')
         b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0., dtype=tf.float32, shape=[self.num_classes], name='b'))

         net = tf.matmul(net, W) + b
         net = tf.reshape(net, [self.batch_size, -1, self.num_classes])

         net = tf.transpose(net, (1, 0, 2))

         loss = tf.nn.ctc_loss(inputs=net, labels=self.labels, sequence_length=[2])

    print(net)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.test.main()
```